# ip from python-digitalocean

Tags: python-3.x, digital-ocean

using python-digitalocean module.

I want to grab the ipv4 after creating the droplet.

```
actions = droplet.get_actions()
for action in actions:
    while action.status != 'completed':
        action.load()
        # Once it shows complete, droplet is up and running
        print (action.status)
print(droplet.ip_address)
```

This will return None

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refresh the droplet data, try like this

```
droplet.load()
print(droplet.ip_address)
```